# Git won't fetch

Tags: git, git-fetch

We managed to clone the repo with a lot of struggling.
But a fetch always just keeps going until it runs into a timeout:
"fatal: unable to access 'https://name@bitbucket.org/company/project.project.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Timed out"

Tried replacing https with ssh in this url. Then it says something like:
"the host fingerprint is not trusted. If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to"

But this is when it's ran from GitExtensions and even though it starts a command line window, inputting "y" doesn't do anything. I've tried [starting plink](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2704) in many ways, no effect.

4 other colleague's are able to fetch and push their changes. We all have roughly the same machines and Windows 7 with roughly the same software (Advertised Programs). Git software I've tried:

- Git Bash
- Git extensions
- SourceTree

Comment: Have you checked which port is used by your colleague's? Or rather protocol. Is it possible to fetch via ssh or plain http? Maybe git? Do you have a firewall on the failing machine?

`git fetch ssh://name@bitbucket.org/company/project.project.git/`